# Why does GDI become unresponsive when I draw a large number (~10k) of simple primitives?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi

I have a MFC app with classical Doc/View architecture. As a performance test I've implemented very simple drawing procedure that draws arcs and stores those arcs in a document of that application.

```
struct CArc
{
    CRect rectClient;
};
```

The problem is that as soon as I reach 10k of those very simple primitives the program becomes unresponsive. Is this normal for GDI and such number of primitives or am I doing something wrong?

```
void CUndo_RedoView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    pDoc_ = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc_);
    if (!pDoc_)
        return;
    for (const auto& x : pDoc_->arcs_)//arcs_ is a vector<CArc>
    {
        pDC->Arc(x.rectClient,
            CPoint(x.rectClient.right, x.rectClient.CenterPoint().y),
            CPoint(x.rectClient.CenterPoint().x, x.rectClient.right));
    }
    // TODO: add draw code for native data here

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are trying to draw 10,000 arcs each time the view is redrawn. Since redrawing happens rather often, doing that much work each time is very likely to cause a slow-down. You might consider double-buffering, which involves drawing the objects to an off-screen bitmap and then in your `OnDraw` event simply blitting that off-screen bitmap to the screen.

Comment: I don't see any errors or resource leaks in the code you have posted. The application has 10,000 GDI limit, but in this code you don't create a single GDI object.

Comment: @CodyGray Hi, thanks man, I believe that this is what I need to do. I'll let you know how it went! Best Regards!

Comment: If you know how many calls you are going to make in advance, it may be possible to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144846(v=vs.85).aspx "SetGdiBatchLimit " to speed up drawing.

Answer (score 0):

GDI is slow.

The prefered method is to use an in-memory DC like MFC's CMemDC (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308997(v=vs.90).aspx) to render your image to only when it is actually modified & then BitBlt the cached image in your next OnPaint call

If you still run into performance issues, consider looking into GDI+ or DirectX